# "Custom" element and directory isses with CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

How do I select a custom style for, lets say text, if the directory is in another folder? From what I understand, all I would have to do is do `whatINeedToEdit.getStyle().add("my_customText");` but since the CSS file is in another folder, I have no idea how to fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZDXC.png)

```
package gameName;
import gameName.Cards.OladamCard;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NodeTester extends Application
{
public static void main( String[]args)
{
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception 
{
    OladamCard oladam = new OladamCard();
    window.setTitle("Tester");
    TextGenerator text = new TextGenerator(oladam.getName());
    text.setSize(45);
    text.embolden();
    //text.dropShadowFromID(oladam.getTextFontID());
    StackPane pane1 = new StackPane();
    text.getText().getStyleClass().add("my_customText");
    text.getText().setStyle("/res/CSS/Test.css/my_customText");
    pane1.getChildren().add(text.getText());
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane1,1000,1000);
    scene1.getStylesheets().add("/res/CSS/Test.css");
    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.show();
}
}
```

CSS:

```
.root{
-fx-background-color:#BDBDBD;
}

.my_customText
{
    text-shadow: -1px 0 #ffff00, 0 1px #ffff00, 1px 0 #ffff00, 0 -1px #ffff00;
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to get an outline for the the text, but CSS is a real strugle for me :P

In this tester I'm just trying to get the text that the generator (it just makes drop shadows, inner shadows, blur effects, ect (And hopefully strokes ;P)) makes to actually interact with the CSS.

Comment: The `setStyle(...)` method is for [inline styles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introstylesheets). So when you call `setStyle(...)` you should pass in some actual CSS rules (as a string), not the URL for a stylesheet. And presumably you meant `getStyleClass().add(...)`, not `getStyle().add(...)`, but you don't call either in the code you posted. It's not really clear what you intend to do here, and what is not working. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @James_D I didn't even realize I had to do that before or that text didn't even have a style class attached to it.

Comment: But `getStyle()` returns a `String`, which obviously doesn't have an `add` method, so the code you quoted in the text of your question doesn't compile. Don't you just need `text.getText().getStyleClass().add("my_customText");` (instead of your `text.getText().setStyle(...)`)? But again, I'm not clear what you have tried and what is not working. Do you see the background color on the root node, for example?

Comment: @James_D Grey background works. Annnnnnd now it works. Thanks for all your help, you just made the last hour of strugling worth it. Want to post that as the annser so I can approve it?

Comment: Oh, wait. `text-shadow` is not a valid JavaFX CSS property. See the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for a list of properties for each node type.

Comment: @James_D Atleast I got it to interact with the text. One strugle at a time.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Summarized comments in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet will be added to the scene and the rules defined in it will be applied to all the nodes in the scene. To get the rules defined for style class `my_customText` to be applied to the text node, you need to give the text node that style class. To do that, replace the line

```
text.getText().setStyle("/res/CSS/Test.css/my_customText");
```

with

```
text.getText().getStyleClass().add("my_customText");
```

Note that the rule you have defined will not work, as `text-shadow` is not a valid JavaFX CSS style property. The properties defined for each node type are listed in the [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).